# How to copy resources to bin folder

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to create a Plug-in project that reads a text file from a folder called "resources" of the same project.

From what I understood is that I need to add this folder to the build.properties like this:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               resources/
```

However, after compiling my bin folder does not include the resources folder nor any of its files.

Is there any obvious mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final plug-in does not normally have a `bin` folder.

The `bin.includes` specifies which folders are copied in to the final plug-in. So your setting will give you a `resources` folder in the plug-in.

Use the `FileLocator` class to find resources in a plug-in.

Comment: This sort of works using the plugin's bundle. However, this does not work for unit tests, unless I set my resources folder as a source folder.

Comment: The tests will be testing the wrong thing if they expect it to be in the bin folder. This will not be the case when the plug-in is built. Things like Class.getResource would appear to work in the test but will fail in the final plug-in.

Comment: What about 3rd party frameworks that expect files to be on the classpath?

Comment: That is a separate and quite complicated question